# Why addEventLister just fire once when Im working with Dom elements trying to toggle classes?

Tags: javascript

My issue is that I'm writing a slider. The slider replace the slide when you click the next button and it works nicely when toggle the 1st class visibleElement, but when reach the second class makeItVisible it stops working. Looks like addEventListener do not work with several DOM changes?

Any help is appreciated.

```js
let slideCount = [1, 2];
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
nextButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var visibleItem = document.querySelector(`#slide${slideCount[0]}`)
    var makeItVisible = document.querySelector(`#slide${slideCount[1]}`);
    visibleItem.classList.toggle('showClass');
    makeItVisible.classList.toggle('showClass');
    slideCount[0] = slideCount[0] + 1;
    slideCount[1] = slideCount[1] + 1;
}, false);
```

```css
.hideClass{
  display: none;
}

.showClass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide1" class="hideClass showClass">
</div>
<div id="slide2" class="hideClass">
</div>
<div id="slide3" class="hideClass">
</div>
<div id="slide4" class="hideClass">
</div>

<button id="nextButton" class="nextButton showButton">
    <a>NEXT</a>
    <i class="material-icons right noselect">arrow_forward_ios</i>
</button>
```

Comment: Willing to be it is do to your rules, but you do not show them so....

Comment: In the code you posted, the event listener fires multiple times (until finally it starts throwing exceptions when it reaches the end and doesn't find further slides)

Comment: That's odd, when I comment this line, `code` makeItVisible.classList.toggle('showClass'); the addEventListener fires multiple times but once I put that line just fires once.

Comment: I've updated the code with CSS rules, thanks @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

You basic logic is heading in the right direction. You can toggle through your slides once. However, your basic logic needs to account for the number of `div`s within the slider.

You are using the `slideCount` array to track with slide is made visible and which is now hidden. You need to add some sort of conditional logic to reset your count when you reach the end or do something else, whatever you choose, once you reach the end. You javascript will throw an error because you attempt to ready `Node` attributes when the results of your `querySelector` logic returns `undefined` or `null`.

**Another Approach**

```js
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
// count all the slides in the slider
var slides = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='slide']");
// initialize count at 2, assuming first slide is defaulted to be visible
var slideCount = 2;
// set a max slideCount
var slideMax = slides.length;

nextButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //only one slide should have showClass
    var visibleItem = document.querySelector('.showClass');
    var makeItVisible = document.querySelector(`#slide${slideCount}`);
    visibleItem.classList.toggle('showClass');
    makeItVisible.classList.toggle('showClass');
    // conditionally either increase slideCount or reset to 1
    slideCount = slideCount < slideMax ? slideCount + 1 : 1;
 
}, false);
```

```css
[id*='slide'] {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

.hideClass{
  display: none;
}

.showClass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide1" class="hideClass showClass">
     1
</div>
<div id="slide2" class="hideClass">
    2
</div>
<div id="slide3" class="hideClass">
    3
</div>
<div id="slide4" class="hideClass">
    4
</div>

<button id="nextButton" class="nextButton showButton">
    <a>NEXT</a>
    <i class="material-icons right noselect">arrow_forward_ios</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was having a div element on slide2 that hide the button, so i just had to put a z-index to that element and the button was clickable again. Thank you everybody.